# Modify dataframes using apply() with loop in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I have a df called `'records'` filled with numbers (0-5) as shown.

One of its column is shown with values 0-3.

[image]

[image]

I want to loop through the dataframe and change all values above 1 to 1 so there will be only 0s and 1s. I came up with this line of code but unsure how to iterate through all df values with apply:

```
records= records.apply(lambda x: 1 if x>1 for x in "something")
```

Comment: Consider avoid saving data elements as column names. Unless doing matrix operations, your data frame should be in long format of two columns: indicator and value.

Answer (score 3):

Convert as bool and as int:

```
records = records.astype(bool).astype(int)
```

Example:

```
>>> records
   A  B  C  D  E
0  2  3  4  1  5
1  0  0  2  5  2
2  1  1  2  0  3
3  0  3  5  4  1
4  2  3  2  0  3
5  2  1  5  2  0
6  0  3  1  3  4
7  1  3  3  2  2
8  1  3  1  5  1
9  4  5  3  4  4

>>> records.astype(bool).astype(int)
   A  B  C  D  E
0  1  1  1  1  1
1  0  0  1  1  1
2  1  1  1  0  1
3  0  1  1  1  1
4  1  1  1  0  1
5  1  1  1  1  0
6  0  1  1  1  1
7  1  1  1  1  1
8  1  1  1  1  1
9  1  1  1  1  1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `df.where`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 0, 2, 5],
                   'B': [0, 2, 3, 4],
                   })

print (df.where(df==0, 1))

   A  B
0  1  0
1  0  1
2  1  1
3  1  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, provide the `axis=1` argument in the apply method.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [`.clip()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html) function, setting upper limit equals 1, as follows:

```
records = records.clip(upper=1)
```

Taking Corralien's sample data, we have

```
print(records)

   A  B  C  D  E
0  2  3  4  1  5
1  0  0  2  5  2
2  1  1  2  0  3
3  0  3  5  4  1
4  2  3  2  0  3
5  2  1  5  2  0
6  0  3  1  3  4
7  1  3  3  2  2
8  1  3  1  5  1
9  4  5  3  4  4

records = records.clip(upper=1)

print(records)

   A  B  C  D  E
0  1  1  1  1  1
1  0  0  1  1  1
2  1  1  1  0  1
3  0  1  1  1  1
4  1  1  1  0  1
5  1  1  1  1  0
6  0  1  1  1  1
7  1  1  1  1  1
8  1  1  1  1  1
9  1  1  1  1  1
```